# Example for $L^p$ and $L^q$ on $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> 1. For $1\le p<q<\infty$, show that neither $L^p(\mathbb{R^n})\subset L^q(\mathbb{R^n}) $ nor $L^q(\mathbb{R^n})\subset L^p(\mathbb{R^n})$.
> 2. Find a measurable function that belongs to $L^p(\mathbb{R^n})$ for all $p>1$ but not for $p=1$.

For Q1, I know some theorems shows the statement is true, since it contains measurable sets with arbitrary large and small measure, but I hope I can show it using an example. I also know how to construct a counterexample in $\mathbb{R}$. But I think this question asks me to find an example for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$? Is my understanding correct? If I only show an example in  $\mathbb{R}$, is it OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototypical example in $\mathbb{R}$ is $1/|x|^\alpha$. Varying $\alpha$ puts this function in various $L^p(\mathbb{R})$-s. You can adapt this example of $\mathbb{R}^n$; you should integrate in polar coordinates to see which $\alpha$-s are needed.

Comment: So for answering this question, you think it's not OK to only discuss the situation for $\mathbb{R}$? I am OK with $\mathbb{R}$ case, but I don't know how to transfer my example from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: May you give an explicit example in $\mathbb{R}^n$? I am not sure how to calculate the measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Just try integrating $1/|x|^\alpha$ over $\mathbb{R}^n$, it should be easy via polar integration since it's radially symmetric. You'll see the required conditions on $\alpha$, and you can handle every $\mathbb{R}^n$ in one go. To integrate a radially symmetric function in polar coordinates, multiply by a scaling factor of $r^{n-1}$ for dimension $n$. There's also a constant factor (the volume of the unit sphere) but we can normalize that to $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. But may you give me a demonstration for one of these two questions? I think that will help me understand your words better.

Comment: May you share a link with me about how to use polar coordinate to integrate in $\mathbb{R}^n, n>3$? Do you mean if the function's symmetric, if I integrate it with respect to a symmetric domain, the integration will be just like integration in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I mean that if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is an integrable function that is radially symmetric, i.e. $f(x)$ depends only on the radius $|x|$, then changing to spherical coordinates $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)dx = \text{Volume}(S^{n-1})\int_0^\infty f(r)r^{n-1}~dr$, where $f(r) = f(|x|)$, $r = |x|$. Exactly like how you would do integration in polar coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ if the function is radially symmetric.

Comment: Thanks I think I know what I should do.